# ActionListener's, Buttons and JPanels

Tags: swing, applet, jpanel, jbutton, actionlistener

I have 5 classes that extend JPanel with at least one JButton on them for "navigation". All five of these classes will eventually become an interactive Applet (I know applets are archaic but I am forced to use them...) When I click a button I want to set the visibility of the current panel to false and set a different panel's visibility to true. Is it possible to add an action listener to my classes that extend JPanel and handle events there? For example here is a small snippet of my constructor:

**NOTE** I get a caution that says "this is leaking in the constructor" on the lines where I add
         the actionListeners

```
public MainPanel()
{
    super();
    setLayout(new BorderLayout());

    search = new JButton("Proceed to Search");
    manager = new JButton("Proceed to Manager Logon");
    search.addActionListener(this);
    manager.addActionListener(this);
}
```

Is the only other option to create instances of each Panel and then add them to my main Applet and handle events from there? What are the implications of this. Currently, all of my Panels have the design I want (a bunch of BorderLayout's with subPanels containing other GUI elements). The only part I have left of my task is to create the user functionality.

Thank you all! The answers on this site are outstanding! :)

Comment: Please show the actual error messages rather than paraphrasing them. The canonical solution to this problem by the way is to use a CardLayout and simply swap JPanels. Also you don't want your GUI class to implement a Listener interface. This is OK for small toy programs but not for larger more complex programs and will make maintenance more difficult. Better to use anonymous or private inner class or even an stand-alone control class for the listener code.

Comment: Hey, Thanks for the idea. How do I add my panels to the CardLayout though? The CardLayout API on the JavaDocs is not very helpful. I have an applet and I set the layout to a CardLayout and I want to do something like this: add(mainView);
        add(managerView);
        add(searchView);
        add(storesView);
        add(hoursView);

Comment: mainView, managerView, searchView, storesView, and hoursView are all Classes I made that extend JPanel

Comment: I am going to post my new question, instead of leaving it here

Comment: Check out the [CardLayout Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html)